# Create <ul> from JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Spent better part of the afternoon on this, can't seem to get it exactly right. I have an external JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "link": "http://www.google.com",
        "pName":"first partner",
        "vTitle":"Video Title",
        "shortDesc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque iusto, culpa mollitia, esse nobis iure.",
        "longDesc":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas excepturi optio harum debitis, sed delectus nisi vel dicta, corporis corrupti, omnis ipsam quaerat. Nemo, voluptatum. Asperiores magnam, iste deleniti maxime. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, recusandae, quod. In assumenda, modi velit itaque enim sunt tempore eum, perspiciatis hic, vitae voluptas. Iste et sint odit molestiae illo."
    }
]
```

I need to create a li from each, and display it.
Here's the closest I got, although its saying one of my items (link) isn't defined:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('./JSON/latest.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        items.push('<li><a href="' + link + '">' + pName + '</a><span class="vTitle">' + vTitle + '</span>' + shortDesc + '</li>');
        });
        $('#latestList').append( items.join('') );
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need an array, just build up your output as a concatenated string.

Comment: Your values are not "link", but should be "item.link", "item.vTitle" etc.

Comment: Jeez I can't believe I missed that. Too many hours at this machine! thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you just need fresh eyeballs. It happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is 'item' so you need to read the properties from that.

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('./JSON/latest.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      items.push(
        '<li>' +
          '<a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.pName + '</a>' +
          '<span class="vTitle">' + item.vTitle + '</span>' +
          item.shortDesc +
        '</li>');
    });
    $('#latestList').append( items.join('') );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify `item.link`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of link and pName and so on

```
item[0].link
item[0].pName
item[0].vTitle
item[0].shortDesc
```